# Is it possible to disable `jest` and other testing libraries when making a new app with `create-react-app`?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I'm doing some small learning projects in React and I'm not planning to test them, therefore I'd like to disable `jest` and any other testing libraries `create-react-app` might automatically install with the `typescript` template from being installed, is there a flag or a way to do that?